# An Android Project Spinoff, standalone Android SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I don't use Android Studio nor Eclipse, but I just got into Android development.

I wrote an app, named project A here. It works just fine!

I wanted to write a similar app, so I copied the whole A project and made the B. I changed the name labels in the manifest, I changed the project name in build.xml, but when I install B it actually overwrites A!

What am I missing? How to install A and B, without removing one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name/application id (in the manifest `manifest` tag `package=...`) are still the same probably.

Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bimjay.timerflow"
    android:versionCode="100"
    ...
```

Comment: They aren't. Here <activity android:name="gerencia.gastos.Expenses" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|mnc|mcc|locale|fontScale|uiMode" android:label="Credit"> and here <activity android:name="gerencia.gastos.Credito" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|mnc|mcc|locale|fontScale|uiMode" android:label="Expenses">

Comment: The package is the same, but the classes aren't. If you got the problem right, I ask you to give more details. Thanks!

Comment: That's the activity tag, the package attribute in the manifest tag

Comment: Not talking about the name or package in the activity element.

Comment: All I have to is change the package name in the application tag? I didn't put that attribute. I'm inserting now: package="different.package". Is that it?

Comment: Sorry meant the manifest tag (clarified that in the answer and comments). But yes that package attribute in the manifest is your application id and identifies you app.

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much!